# How to connect a signal from the controller in PyQt4? (iOS like MVC structure in PyQt4)

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt4

Why doesn't the following example work?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class TestView(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestView, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.btn.resize(self.btn.sizeHint())
        self.btn.move(50, 50)

class TestViewController():

    def __init__(self, view):
        view.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        view.show()

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print 'clicked'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = TestView()
    TestViewController(view)
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The example is supposed to represent an MVC structure (like the one in [Figure 4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) -- without the Model) where the controller (`TestViewController`) receives a reference to the view (`TestView`) and connects the clicked signal from the view's button `view.btn` to its function `self.buttonClicked`.

I'm sure the line `view.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)` is executed but, apparently, it has no effect. Does anyone knows how to solve that?

---

**Update (awful solution):**

In the example, if I replace the line

```
view.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
```

with

```
view.clicked = self.clicked
view.btn.clicked.connect(view.clicked)
```

it works. I'm still not happy with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because the controller class is being garbage collected before you can ever click anything for it.

When you set view.clicked = self.clicked, what you're actually doing is making one of the objects from the controller persist on the view object so it never gets cleaned up - which isn't really the solution.

If you store your controller to a variable, it will protect it from collection.

So if you change your code above to read:

```
ctrl = TestViewController(view)
```

You'll be all set.

That being said - what exactly you are trying to do here, I am not sure...it seems you're trying to setup an MVC system for Qt - but Qt already has a pretty good system for that using the Qt Designer to separate the interface components into UI (view/template) files from controller logic (QWidget subclasses).  Again, I don't know what you are trying to do and this may be a dumb down version of it, but I'd recommend making it all one class like so:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

class TestView(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestView, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.btn.resize(self.btn.sizeHint())
        self.btn.move(50, 50)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print 'clicked'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = TestView()
    view.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit: Clarifying the MVC of Qt**

So this above example doesn't actually load the ui dynamically and create a controller/view separation.  Its a bit hard to show on here.  Best to work through some Qt/Designer based examples/tutorials - I have one here http://bitesofcode.blogspot.com/2011/10/introduction-to-designer.html but many can be found online.

The short answer is, your loadUi method can be replace with a PyQt4.uic dynamic load (and there are a number of different ways to set that up) such that your code ultimately reads something like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import PyQt4.uic
import sys

class TestController(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestController, self).__init__()

        # load view
        uifile = '/path/to/some/widget.ui'
        PyQt4.uic.loadUi(uifile, self)

        # create connections (assuming there is a widget called 'btn' that is loaded)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print 'clicked'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = TestController()
    view.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit 2: Storing UI references**

If it is easier to visualize this concept, you Can also store a reference to the generated UI object:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import PyQt4.uic
import sys

class TestController(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestController, self).__init__()

        # load a view from an external template
        uifile = '/path/to/some/widget.ui'
        self.ui = PyQt4.uic.loadUi(uifile, self)

        # create connections (assuming there is a widget called 'btn' that is loaded)
        self.ui.btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print 'clicked'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = TestController()
    view.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The "assign controller to a variable" part is nice! Although, I would like to point out that the second part of your answer seems a bit contradictory. First of all, that is just a working example of what I'm trying to achieve. Second, you recommend the use of QtDesigner to separate View from the logic but then you show an example where all the elements of the program are in a single class. Notice that, in my example, the `TestView` class contains only UI elements and not a single line of "logic". The next step would be to forward the "clicked" call to the Model's API through the controller.

Comment: Yea, you're right - I didn't actually change your code at all, displaying how to use designer on here isn't as easy.  Here's a tutorial: http://bitesofcode.blogspot.com/2011/10/introduction-to-designer.html

Comment: Right, I get your point. But since your connections are made inside the view, it would have to have a reference to its controller object, correct? That could be solved by making the connections inside the controller, which would be the glue between view and model.

Comment: I guess, the better example would be to call it TestController(QtGui.QWidget) vs. TestView.  The class is the controller, the view would be entirely defined the UI file.  Another way to set this up is to store a pointer to the resolved class instance if it is easier to visualize.  I'm not saying you can't do it the way your suggesting, I've just never seen Qt used that way and it just feels to me to be over engineered, applying website structure/logic to desktop systems.

Comment: That structure was actually inspired by mobile systems. For some applications (mostly the simpler ones) it may be over engineered, but if you have complex commands from multiple domains in the same window, you may want to assign multiple controllers also to manage parts of that window. I'm not saying that yours is wrong, since there is no absolute truth in software engineering. It is just that most of the time it is useful to have a well partitioned, flexible structure. Btw, your second edit enhances the view-controller partitioning. Very good! =D