# PyQt signal between QObjects

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, slot

I'm trying to make a view and controller in PyQt where the view is emitting a custom signal when a button is clicked, and the controller has one of its methods connected to the emitted signal.  It does not work, however.  The respond method is not called when I click the button.  Any idea what I did wrong ?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QApplication 

class TestView(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton('Click')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.connect(self.button, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL('request'))

class TestController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view
        self.connect(self.view, SIGNAL('request'), self.respond)

    def respond(self):
        print 'respond'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = TestView()
controller = TestController(dialog)
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4):

Works for me - might be the version of Qt/PyQt you're using, but there are a couple things you can try:

1. Use a proper method syntax - so SIGNAL('request()') vs. SIGNAL('request')
2. Use new-style signal syntax

The style you are using is the old-style PyQt syntax and the new-style signal/slot definition is recommended:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal  # really shouldn't import * here...QtCore library is quite large
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QApplication 

class TestView(QDialog):
    request = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton('Click')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.request.emit()

class TestController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, view):
        super(QObject, self).__init__()
        self.view = view
        self.view.request.connect(self.respond)

    def respond(self):

        print 'respond'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = TestView()
controller = TestController(dialog)
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Again tho, I would really, really discourage building your code this way...you are creating a lot of unnecessary work and duplication of objects when you don't need to.

Comment: In the mean time, I found out that I should have called QObject's init in the __init__ of my TestController: QObject.__init__(self)  Thanks for your advice, Eric, much appreciated.  If I understand correctly, you would encourage to handle the button click directly in the buttonClicked method of TestView ?

Comment: Oops, yea, I missed that - that is most likely causing a problem...weird it worked on my test, it probably should have failed for me too.  I thought you were the same person who asked this question as it is almost exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270327/how-to-connect-a-signal-from-the-controller-in-pyqt4-ios-like-mvc-structure-in/12270732#comment16470313_12270732